# Entity Framework Database Design Foreign Key and Table linking

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

Ok I have a master table which can be designed in two different ways, and I'm unsure of the best approach.  I am doing model first programming in regards to setting up the database.

I have 5 tables so far.

```
Master table
Departments
Functions
Processes
Procedures
```

Which is a better way to handle the design?

**Idea #1:**

Master Table

```
masterId, departmentID, functionID, processID, procedureID, user1, date
```

Should I make it this way and then provide a FK from master to the departments table, functions table, processess table and procedures table?

**Idea #2**

Master Table

```
MasterID, departmentID, user1, date
```

This table will link to Departments table, which will then link to functions, which will link to processes which will link to procedures.

The master table will have a complete list of everything.

```
A department can have many functions.
a function can have many processes.
a process can have many procedures.
```

Which of the ways is best or am I just doing it completely wrong and someone can tell me thee or close to thee best way to create this diagram of tables and linking structure?

Comment: If all the data already exists in other tables, why do you need the master?

Comment: because the master table will have data not available in other tables. @Kami

Comment: Idea 1 makes sense to me as it reduces joins in the long run allowing you to filter based on IDs pretty efficiently.   However database design would say if they don't directly relate then idea 2 is better as you will not have null values in processID, procedureId.  In addition Idea 1 results in more data duplication.  The real question to me is what is known by the user when entering this data? is the hierachy known to teh user and thus may be easier to traverse in idea 2 or is dealing with all the data at a "master" level more common to the user/group?  <there is no silver bullet here>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following criteria,

```
A master can have many departments.
a department can have many functions.
a function can have many processes.
a process can have many procedures.
```

Then you must use your second design idea.  You only have one department, one function, one process, and one procedure key in your first design idea.

```
Master
------
Master ID
User
Date
...

Department
----------
Department ID
Master ID
...

Function
--------
Function ID
Department ID
...
```

and so on.

The primary key of each table is an auto incrementing integer or long.

The foreign keys are identified by name.

Comment: Yeah I'm leaning toward #2.  But for #1 it could still work, it would just mean I would have a lookup table referencing each of the 4 id's in the master table.  I'm actually thinking of getting rid of the master table all together and just moving the data to more relevant tables.